# Why am I getting a "function not defined" error when there are 2 functions in the script tag?

Tags: javascript, html

The script tag part in `<head>`:

```
  function reload()
  {
     //some code


  }
  function bookconfirm(clickinfo)
  {
        //some code
  }
```

The part that are calling them:

```
           <select name="city" onchange="reload()">

          <td><button type="button" onclick="bookconfirm(<?php echo $c;?>)">Book</button></td>
```

Errors:

```
             Uncaught ReferenceError: reload is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange


        Uncaught ReferenceError: bookconfirm is not defined  at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

I'm probably unable to understand how functions work in js or something , thanks for your time and knowledge.

Comment: Where are your `<script>` tags that import your functions in that HTML file that's calling them?

Comment: I suspect that your functions aren't globals. One of the many problems with `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers is that the functions they call have to be globals. If your functions were at the top level of your script (and it's not `type="module"`), then your functions would be globals and those handlers would work. So apparently, they're inside something, or you're using `type="module"`. Use modern event handling instead ([`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and such).

Comment: @AJC24 - The thing is, it wouldn't really matter because by the time the user is clicking, they'd presumably be loaded. But the OP said they're in `head`.

Answer (score -1):

seems to work fine.  Make sure your html is correct, your select statement needs some fine tuning.  also make sure the html appears before the script is called.
(i.e. place the script just before the closing body tag, although in this case you can also keep it in the head tag but remember you can get errors if the javascript tries to execute before the the dom is fully loaded)

```js
 function reload()
  {
     console.log('reload');


  }
  function bookconfirm(clickinfo)
  {
     console.log(clickinfo);
  }
```

```html
 
           <select name="city" onchange="reload()">
           <option></option>
           <option>test</option>
           </select>

         <button type="button" onclick="bookconfirm('bookconfirm')">Book</button>
```

Comment: "It seems to work" is a *comment*, not an answer. The question can't be answered in its current form. Posting premature answers prevents the OP from deleting their question if they realize they've made a basic mistake or need more time to present their question clearly.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, very impressive rep but I disagree.  It seems to work, while a comment, indicates that when done right the code works. The question can be answered in its current form and the problems with the code are listed.  A little tolerance goes a long way in helping newcomers.

Comment: That's fine, we can disagree. :-) (And I like to think I'm quite tolerant with newcomers! I post comments I hope are helpful, sometimes link to a jsFiddle when doing a "works for me" style comment, etc.) *(not my downvote, btw)*